# Encode class names in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I am experimenting with Tensorflow and I have the dataset loaded. When I do
`raw_train_ds.class_names` i get `['neg', 'pos']`. Is there a way I can encode this class as `0 or 1` in the same tensorflow dataset?

Comment: Does raw_train_ds.class_names = [0, 1] work for you?